# convert output from sqlite from tuple to list in Python

Tags: python, sqlite, csv

I am new to programming and am writing a simple python script that will gather some information from a PC for forensic purposes.  Some of the information I want is the Chrome history.  Basically I need to read the data from the history sqlite database, perform a calculation to convert the time stamp to a human readable format, and then write the data to a CSV file.  I have the following code:

```
connection = sqlite3.connect('c:\history')### need correct path
connection.text_factory = str
cur = connection.cursor()
output_file = open('chrome_history2.csv', 'wb')
csv_writer = csv.writer(output_file,)
headers = ('URL', 'Title', 'Visit Count', 'Last Visit')
csv_writer.writerow(headers)
epoch = datetime(1601, 1, 1)
for row in (cur.execute('select url, title, visit_count, last_visit_time from urls limit 10')): #selects data
        list(row) #convert to list - does not work
        url_time = epoch + timedelta(microseconds=row[3]) #calculates time
        row[3] = url_time #changes value in row to readable time
        csv_writer.writerow(row)
connection.close()
```

This code returns the error:

```
TypeError: 'tuple' object does not support item assignment
```

I understand that I can't manipulate the data in a tuple but I am explicitly converting each row to a list. Can anyone explain
a) why 
    list (row)
does not work, and b) a better way to do it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `list` does not change a value in place, it **returns** a new list.

Comment: `list(row)` returns a new list, which you throw away. `row = list(row)` would work.

Comment: It's good to try things in the command prompt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that:

```
        list(row) #convert to list - does not work
```

Should be:

```
        row = list(row) #convert to list
```

In addition, you may want to look into using a `csv.DictReader` object instead of the default reader, as it may be more convenient (and is mutable, unlike the default tuple). See https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.DictReader for detauls.

Comment: Yep - that fixed it.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Another work around would be like this-->

```
    conn = sqlite3.connect('library.db')
    conn.row_factory = lambda cursor, row: row[0]
    c = conn.cursor()

    id_sql = 'SELECT emp_id FROM teachtable WHERE teach_name = "%s"' % (name1)
    id_no = c.execute(id_sql).fetchall()
    conn.commit()
    conn.close()
    # This list output can be used to iterate through it in a for loop
    
    # print the first element from the list
    idno = id_no[0]
    print(id_no)
```

Here's [a reference link to understand how "row_factory" object is used to return the query output as a list](https://www.kite.com/python/docs/sqlite3.Connection.row_factory)!